# Datajoint LabBook - can't get past login screen

Tags: datajoint

I set up the datajoint lab book (docker, https://datajoint.github.io/datajoint-labbook/user.html#installation) and it seems to run. However, I can’t seem to get past the login screen (credentials / db server are correct). When I click on the green connect button nothing happens. How can I debug?

Comment: Strange... Recommended method for debugging is using the Google Chrome Developer Tools (CTRL + F12 for most OS'). Could you access it, click on the Network tab, try again and update your question with the result? Typically any errors would be in red with more details in the console. Feel free to add any screenshots if appropriate. Also, where are you running the server? Locally or is it being run somewhere remotely? Asking to verify that the machine where you've deployed has access and can reach the database server in question.

Comment: Under the Network tab it shows me a red error "login", und "Headers" I can see "Status Code 502 Bad Gateway". Type: Fetch, "Login.tsx" Line 101.  I am running this remotely on a university server (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: There seems to be a network issue. I'll make some debugging suggestions here but PLEASE REDACT  the following to prevent exposing publicly: DATABASE_SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, JWT, LABBOOK_SERVER, LABBOOK_PORT. Ensure you have curl (or equivalent) installed and try on the client machine these two requests and update your question with the results: curl -vk https://${LABBOOK_SERVER}:${LABBOOK_PORT}/api/version. curl -vkX POST https://${LABBOOK_SERVER}:${LABBOOK_PORT}/api/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"databaseAddress": "X.X.X.X", "username": "user", "password": "pass123"}'.